# R - invert gsub: keep only matches with gsub argument

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm running through a character vector (approx 10,000 entries) and it has a lot of information in it I wish to discard, but quite a bit that I want to keep. The information I want to keep has to match a given string in another character vector. So, this would be the `matching_points` vector containing the arguments that satisfy the matching criteria:

```
matching_points <- "house|techno|pop|jazz|dreampop|artrock"
```

and this would be the vector i'd want to clean up:

```
music <- c("tropical house", "tech house", "funk", "hardcore", "hard rock", "pop", "dream pop", "free jazz")
```

and through the cleanup operation, I'd want the vector `music` to then look like this

```
[1] "house"  "house"  ""  ""  ""  "pop"  "pop"  "jazz"
```

It would be great if anyone had any idea how I can do this - I suspect there's a simple option that can be applied to the `gsub` process in order to invert the process, i.e. keep the stuff that matches and replacing everything else with `""`.

Comment: `regmatches(music, regexpr(matching_points, music))` almost works... not sure how best to get the ""s.

Comment: Hm, I guess the linked answer covers it. Let me know if not.

Comment: Hi @Frank, thanks for your help. Sotos method worked perfectly.

Comment: @Frank I think some variation of `regmatches(music, regexpr(matching_points, music, invert=NA))` might work for R >= 3.3.0. I can't test now as I'm working with 3.2.3.

Comment: @lmo I'd be curious to know. I'm sticking with 3.2.5 myself and so also cannot/will not test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `stringr`,

```
library(stringr) 
str_extract(music, matching_points)
#[1] "house" "house" NA      NA      NA      "pop"   "pop"   "jazz"
```

Comment: awesome, this worked! thank you so much!